# How to pass the content (text)of a summernote to a <p> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
function PasarValor() {
  
  var htmlContent = $('#summernote').summernote('code');
  document.getElementById("idTitulo").innerHTML = $(htmlContent).text();
  // document.getElementById("idTitulo").innerHTML = document.getElementById("summernote").value;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bootstrap4</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="idTitulo">
ESCRIBE ENCABEZADO....
</p>
    <div id="summernote" onkeyup="PasarValor();"></div>
    <script>
      $('#summernote').summernote({
        toolbar: [
    ['style', ['style']],
    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
    ['color', ['color']],
    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
    ['height', ['height']],
    ['help', ['help']]
  ],
        width: 530,
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to pass the text that i write in the `summernote` with the options that it has, for example, if the text is red  i want to take all the text and copy it to the `p` tag with the properties that in the summernote has apply (like the red color, alignment, etc).

Comment: Hi, please post your question in english for that the maximum of person can understand or go to the es stackoverflow : https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should translate the question to english, second summernote has a `callback` property that let you hear for events, so in your initialization you could add the callback with the event you want

```
$('#summernote').summernote({
    toolbar: [
      ['style', ['style']],
      ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
      ['fontname', ['fontname']],
      ['color', ['color']],
      ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
      ['height', ['height']],
      ['help', ['help']]
    ],
    width: 530,
    //add the callback with the event
    callbacks: {
      //listen to keyup
      onKeyup: function() {
            //lastly we get the editor html with $('#summernote').summernote('code') and paste it in the #idTitulo 
            $('#idTitulo').html($('#summernote').summernote('code'))
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, and if for the other I ask the question in English, it's my first time asking a question I'm sorry.

Comment: Can you pass with everything and the attributes to (paragraph) for example the color?

Comment: yes it will update te p with every you have writen in the editor, with the options, but it will only update on keyboard events.